# Cannot inject Worker using @WorkerInject

Tags: kotlin, dagger-hilt

I'm trying to inject data into my Worker, but the `@WorkerInject` is giving me an `unresolved reference`.
Bear in mind I have these defined in my gradle:

```
def hilt_version = '2.38.1'
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
    def hilt_worker_version = '1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-work:$hilt_worker_version"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:$hilt_worker_version"
```

And this is my Worker class:

```
class MyWorker @WorkerInject constructor(
    @Assisted val context: Context,
    @Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters
) :
    Worker(context, workerParams) { ... }
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/dependency-injection/hilt-jetpack#workmanager

Comment: I've refered to that... The @WorkerInject annotation is unresolved...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a new way to annotate this class:

```
@HiltWorker
class MyWorker @AssisstedInject constructor(
    @Assisted val context: Context,
    @Assisted workerParams: WorkerParameters
) :
Worker(context, workerParams) { ... }
```

Comment: @AssistedInject